# Storing 3bits documents in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

To make a real time collaborative online canvas, I want to use firebase.

Firestore only supports 64 bits numbers. Huge canvas could be 10 millions pixels, so 80 Mo. That's too much.

So I want to restrict users to 16 colors, and store thoses colors on 3 bits.

How can I have fields with a value of 3 bits in a firestore document?

Storing arrays of 3 booleans could do the trick, but I'm not sure this will really be 3 bits, and I'm hoping there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Aren't you essentially asking [how to store multiple bits in a 64-bit number](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+store+multiple+bits+in+a+64-bit+number+in+javascript)?

Comment: There's no way to directly limit the size of numbers stored in Firestore, though you can use bit masking when writing and reading.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing this as community wiki for other's sake.

---

as @Nick Felker said:

> There's no way to directly limit the size of numbers stored in Firestore, though you can use bit masking when writing and reading.

---

Reference:

- [Storage Size Calculations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size)